# Can I receive large files from anyone via Google Drive?

Tags: google-drive, google-workspace

Our business uses Google Apps for email/ file storage etc.

Occasionally our clients need to send us files that are simply too large to be sent as email attachments. We're talking hundreds of megabytes.

Is there anyway to invite someone via e-mail to upload files to Google Drive?

We have no control over our clients IT environment but in almost all cases they'd have a modern browser, good network connectivity and the ability to do http uploads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your company is using Google Apps then as Baljeet said your best solution would be GoFileDrop, [click here](https://gofiledrop.appspot.com/settings) to activate it on your Google Account, you will then be able to send a link to your clients who can upload directly to your Google Drive account (without needing to use Google Apps or Gmail on their side). GoFileDrop basically gives deposit only access via a web browser for clients to drop files in your account.

Answer (score 1):

Currently (AFAIK), the only way someone can upload a file to you, is to have a Google Drive (that is to say, a Google account) of his own, and have you share a folder with him, allowing him to edit folder contents. Be aware that there's a limit on the file size (10GB) and on the total sizes of all files (15GB) - unless you pay for the service (see ["other files"](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/37603?hl=en)).

You can use other file sharing services, such as Dropbox, or Box.com to allow customers to share files. Alternatively, you could run a dedicated FTP server, and avoid limitations/registration.

Answer (score 1):

Exactly for this purpose we have developed a new online service

https://driveuploader.com/

We had the same problem. Our clients are sending us very large files quite often. The DriveUploader service supports the transfer of files with up to hundreds of gigabytes!!! (yes, we have tested this and received such a large data from our customers).

The service comes with a free plan - where you create a time-limited private upload link, which is sent by email to the persons who upload any large data to a folder of your choice in your Google Drive. They don't need to log-in anywhere, just use drag&drop into their web browser.

You can also embed the service in your websites via iframe and brand it with your company logo, with minimal technical knowledge.

The uploading component comes with a nice look&feel:

[image: Drive Uploader]

Developers can also use the stable and tested uploading component via a JavaScript API and integrate it easily with their products - and trigger any action with configured webhook after a successful upload. Technical details are at https://driveuploader.com/api/

I hope you (and others) find this service useful...

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, it is possible to send large files as you asked 100's of MB.
2. Just create new folder in the google drive.
3. Right click on the created folder and select share and type the email adress of the person with which you want to share the folder. One important thing here is to change the privileges to read and write both.
4. Now this folder will appear on the drive of the person with which you shared.
5. Now whatever he/she put in this folder will be accessible to you and vice versa.

Comment: This works fine for us sending large files to clients - but not for clients who want to send large files to us.

Comment: @Tama i think you need something like [GoFileDrop](http://www.gofiledrop.com/)